# Flask with Heroku, Import Error: No module named Flask

Tags: python, heroku, flask

So I'm trying to create an app with Flask and Heroku. I can run it with Foreman just fine, but after deploying to Heroku, the application error comes up and the heroku logs show:

```
heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python app.py`
app[web.1]:   File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
app[web.1]:     from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named flask
```

Any idea on how this could happen? Thanks!

EDIT: Flask is in the requirements file and I see that it gets installed during the push to Heroku.

Comment: Is flask in requirements.txt? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#prepare-the-app

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add Flask (and any other external dependencies) to a requirements.txt and include it in your repo.

You can use 'pip freeze > requirements.txt" to create it with what ever packages you have installed in your environment at the moment.

Comment: I created the requirements.txt and pushed it to the heroku repo. It installed them as well: Downloading/unpacking Flask==0.10.1

Comment: Yes, almost the same for me, I have Flask==0.12 and I get a ModuleNotFoundError

Comment: I have same issue, although Flask is included in "requirements.txt", I get ModuleNotFoundError. If u guys solve the problem, could u share it?